# Unable to consume WCF service with javascript (readyState goes from 1 to 4)

Tags: c#, javascript, wcf

Whenever I try to consume the WCF using the javascript below in an external file, the readyState goes from 1 to 4. The ResponsText is always empty in every case.

Whenever I try to consume the WCF using the same code, but this time in the project itself, it's working as it is supposed to.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

I have an interface

```
namespace CeviService
{
     [ServiceContract(Namespace = "CeviService")]
    public interface ICeviSpotter
    {

         [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
          String EchoWithPost(string n1, string n2);
  }

}
```

with an implementation

```
namespace CeviService
{
public class CeviSpotter : ICeviSpotter
{
     public String EchoWithPost(String n1, String n2)
    {
        return n1;
    }
}}
```

using the following web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="AjaxBehavior">
                    <webHttp/>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
        <services>
            <service name="CeviService.CeviSpotter" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
                <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex"/>
                <endpoint address="ajaxEndpoint" behaviorConfiguration="AjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="CeviService.ICeviSpotter"/>
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true"/></system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

that is called using the following javascript:

```
 function makeCall(operation) {

        // Create HTTP request
        var xmlHttp;
        try {
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                try {
                    xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {
                    alert("This sample only works in browsers with AJAX support");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        // Create result handler
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            alert(xmlHttp.readyState);
              //  alert(xmlHttp.responseText);

        }

        // Build the operation URL
        var url = "http://localhost:49456/CeviSpotter.svc/ajaxendpoint/EchoWithPost";
        //url = url + operation;

        // Build the body of the JSON message
        var val1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
        var val2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;


        var body = '{"n1":';
        body = body + val1 + ',"n2":';
        body = body + val2 + '}';

        // Send the HTTP request
        xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        xmlHttp.send(body);

    }
```

and the host being configured as follows:

```
<%@ServiceHost 
    language="C#"
    Debug="true"
    Service="CeviService.CeviSpotter"
%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the page containing the JavaScript isn't being served from `http://localhost:49456` (including the port number), the problem is that you're trying to make a cross-origin call, which is blocked by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). So for instance, if you're using that JavaScript in a file you've opened by double-clicking it in a file explorer (and so its protocol is `file://`), or you're loading it from `http://localhost` (without using port 49456), etc.

You could enable access using [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) by handling the pre-flight call and responding with the appropriate headers (provided you're using a [browser that supports CORS](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors)).

Comment: Thanks TJ. Is there any workaround for this problem? How do we fix this? The WCF service is supposed to be ran on a host so it becomes accessible for mobile applications.

EDIT: Does the Cross Oroigin Resource Sharing work for the intended use?

Comment: @JensCocquyt: CORS is an option, as I mention in the answer. If CORS isn't an option, I don't know much about WCF services, but if what it produces can be in a variety of formats, you might look at [JSON-P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP).

Comment: Thanks T.J. Crowder. We indeed were able to fix it with CORS. Info that helped me: [CORS on client](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) [CORS in wcf service](http://blog.weareon.net/calling-wcf-rest-service-from-jquery-causes-405-method-not-allowed/)